# How can I convert octal to hexadecimal?

Tags: c, hex, octal

How can I convert octal numbers to hexadecimal and hexadecimal to octal in C language?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not clear. Do you want to know how to convert a string that represents an octal number to another string that represents the same number, but with hexadecimal digits?

Comment: First, how would you do it with paper and pencil? Can you write a main() function which defines a variable which holds the input you want to convert and another one which will contain the output ?

Comment: You might not even need to do this. Numbers are numbers and their specific representation is only for input/output. So this question has no good answer until the specific problem is presented.

Comment: On paper, you successively divide the resulting octal quotients by `020`, and keep track of the remainders, until your quotient is 0. You translate `000` ... `017` to `0x0` ... `0xF` when transcribing the octal remainders into hexadecimal digits.

Comment: @jxh I find it much easier to to go octal->binary->hex. No math involved, only need to know binary representation of 0-15

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, that's easier in terms of mechanics, but explain that shifting by 4 bits is the same as dividing by 16.

Answer (score 2):

Since the concept of a radix only makes sense when describing the representation or output of a number, I'll assume you mean "how can I convert between octal and hexadecimal *representations* of a number?"

Lucky for you, the `printf`-family functions are required by the C standard to include the format specifiers `%o` and `%x`, which represent "octal number" and "hexadecimal number", respectively, so with `snprintf`, you could do this:

```
char buffer[100];

snprintf(buffer, 100, "%X", 0777);
printf("%s\n", buffer);

snprintf(buffer, 100, "%o", 0xFFF);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Output:

```
1FF
7777
```

Also, the `strtol`-family functions have a radix parameter for converting a string to a number:

```
int n;

n = strtol("0777", NULL, 8);
printf("%d\n", n);

n = strtol("0x1FF", NULL, 16);
printf("%d\n", n);
```

Output:

```
511
511
```

With these building blocks you now possess the requisite knowledge to process input in the form of, and convert between, octal and hexadecimal representations of numeric values.